# django　??? has no column named ???　というエラーについてです。

Tags: python, django

```
operational error targetuser　has no column named name
```

というエラーが生じます。
考えられる可能性としてもう一度マイグレーションしてみましたが、最新でした。
このエラーの原因はなんでしょうか

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class TargetUser(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=16)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    level=models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

views.py内の関数

```
def register(request):
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        if (request.POST['password']==request.POST['again']):
            name=request.POST['name']
            password=request.POST['password']
            user=TargetUser(name=name,password=password)
            user.save()
            return redirect(to='/target/index')
        else:
            messages.success(request,'パスワードが異なります。<br>もう一度試してください。')
            return redirect(to='target/register')
    params={
        'form':CreateUserForm()
    }
    return render(request,'target/register.html',params)
```

Comment: 再度マイグレーションする際、どんなコマンドを実行しましたか？　特に、`python manage.py migrate` でしょうか `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` でしょうか。

Comment: python3.7 manage.py makemigration アプリ名　python3.7 manage.py migrate で行いました。